# Changing ImageButton position and content at the same time in onClick

Tags: android, position, imagebutton, android-view, android-button

I'm making a simple app to help me learn some coding fundamentals. The user clicks an `ImageButton` and two things happen:

1. The `Button` image changes to a random image.
2. The `Button` moves to a random location on the screen.

I have figured out how to do both of these things in isolation, but when I put both together in an `onClick` however, only one will work at a time.

The `onClick` code:

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {

            // change button image
            int imgNo = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1; // 9 images in the folder, start at index 1
            int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("chef" + imgNo, "drawable", getPackageName());
            v.setBackgroundResource(imgID);

            // move button to a random location
            LinearLayout button_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_window);
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * (button_container.getWidth() - v.getWidth())); // might need to work out how to find if phone is landscape or portrait;
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * (button_container.getHeight() - v.getHeight()));
            v.layout(x, y, x + v.getWidth(), y + v.getHeight());

            Toast.makeText(WhackachefActivity.this, "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + " Width: " + v.getWidth() + " Height: " + v.getHeight() + " Image: " + imgNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }
    });
```

The `Toast` is just in there to prove all the variables are working correctly. If either the location change or the image change code is commented out, the other works fine. If the image is randomly set to the current image (i.e. no change in image) then the random location works, but otherwise it's set to the default location in the XML.

For reference, the main `XML` is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/my_window" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    />
```

As a follow-up, two related questions:

1. How can I make the onClick code run once when the app is first loaded?
2. How can I make the ImageButton size itself automatically (i.e. to fit the sizes of the random images, which are slightly different, without stretching them)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for the main question, I don't have an answer offhand -- I'm not sure why it would work if you're just removing the background resource, but perhaps if you change the background resource after the layout? Worth a shot, but that doesn't really explain why that would happen.

Now the "bonus points" questions, I can answer:

1: Simply call `imageButton.performClick()` in your `onCreate()` (after assigning your `OnClickListener`, of course).

2: Set the `ImageButton`'s `LayoutParams` to `wrap_content`, `wrap_content`, and then call `imageButton.requestLayout();`. It should then be sized to fit the content.

Comment: Thanks kcoppock - performClick() and requestLayout() solve my secondary issues. I checked and the primary issue of not being able to do both at once is still there. In terms of the order, logically I'd want to change the image first so I can position it using its new dimensions, but I have tested it both ways and the order doesn't seem to matter in terms of my main issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution which works - using the padding of the LinearLayout to move the button instead of using .layout. The main activity code (with a few minor changes along the way) now looks like this:

```
final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
final LinearLayout button_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_window);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {

        // change button image
        int imgNo = (int) (Math.random() * 9) + 1; // 9 images in the folder, start at index 1
        int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("chef" + imgNo, "drawable", getPackageName());
        button.setBackgroundResource(imgID);
        button.requestLayout(); // size to fit content

        // move button to a random location
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * (button_container.getWidth() - button.getWidth()));
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * (button_container.getHeight() - button.getHeight()));
        button_container.setPadding(x, y, 0, 0);
    }   
});
button.performClick(); // run once at the start to set image and position randomly
```